# How to set schedule time of clock in Kivy while using Python?

Tags: python, debugging, kivy

I am trying to make the program using Kivy in Python in which a particular function do executes after certain period of time.

```
def repeat(dt):
    print "My callback is called",dt
Clock.schedule_interval(repeat,1/30.)
```

The above is the code that i have wrote down but there is a error whose image i am attaching with this description. Please help me out and guide me how to work with Kivy in Python in a productive manner.[image: error log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the Clock:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
```

Comment: Thanks it is working and i am not receiving any error now but the thing is no any output neither in console nor in Kivy window. What should i do now?